# tuple to dict

Tags: python

```
g = (('a','1'),('a','2'),('b','1'),('b','2'))
dict((y, x) for y, x in g)
{'a': '2', 'b': '2'}
```

Как получить все ключи и значение в dict?

Comment: Вам не нравиться что в словаре осталось только два значения?

Comment: на то он и dict, что ключи уникальные.

Comment: Да, и кстати, для python 2.6
g = (('a','1'),('a','2'),('b','1'),('b','2'))
dict(g)
{'a': '2', 'b': '2'}

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял, вам нужен некий аналог multimap из C++. В python такого нет, но
можно просто использовать dict, который хранит списки:

```
import collections
from collections import defaultdict

g = (('a','1'),('a','2'),('b','1'),('b','2'))
d = defaultdict(list)
[d[x].append(y) for (x, y) in g]
print d

>>> defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': ['1', '2'], 'b': ['1', '2']})
```

Comment: Взять

    g = (('Framed-IP-Address', '10.6.11.1'), 
    ('Framed-IP-Netmask', '255.255.255.255'), 
    ('Cisco-Account-Info', 'AUNL_10M_DAY'), 
    ('Cisco-Account-Info', 'ALOCAL'), 
    ('Cisco-Account-Info', 'AUNL_20M_NIGHT'), 
    ('Idle-Timeout', '86400'))

    и получить 

    {'Cisco-Account-Info': 'AUNL_20M_NIGHT',
    'Cisco-Account-Info': 'AUNL_10M_DAY',
    'Cisco-Account-Info': 'LOCAL', 
    'Framed-IP-Address': '10.6.11.1',
    'Framed-IP-Netmask': '255.255.255.255',
    'Idle-Timeout': '86400'}

Comment: Это невозможно. Ключи должны быть уникальными!

Comment: Вы хотите невозможного. dict - это контейнер, в котором каждому ключу соответствует уникальное значение.

Comment: Спасибо, за разъяснения!

Comment: dzhioev, Вы вводите человека в заблуждение своим комментарием, в корне неверным. Посмотрите комментарий выше - он правильный.

Comment: dude, да неправильно сформулировал. Хотел написать, что каждому ключу соостветствует только одно значение.